# Shared Preference Flutter(How to use Shared preference in build method)

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, flutter-dependencies

Hi I'm new to flutter and I'm struggling to use shared preference inside the builder method, Here is my code:

```
getId() async {
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      String sessionId = prefs.getString('sessionId');
      return Text(sessionId);
    }
```

This is a piece of my build method:

```
ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    'Welcome, $getId()',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
```

Here's the error output that I get for trying to use the shared pref inside a text widget:

```
dynamic function closure flutter
```

Comment: The important part for you is the "how do I use it" part. although it cannot hurt to brush up on the other details as well.

Comment: getId() is returning Text widget instead of string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `FutureBuilder` widget

Example:

```
FutureBuilder(
      future: getId(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData){
          return ListTile(
              title: Text(
                'Welcome, ${snapshot.data}',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
        }else if (snapshot.hasError){
          return Container(); //Error getting data
        }else{
          return Container(); //show Loading
        }
      },);
```

And in your `getId()` return String instead of a Text Widget
Example:

```
getId() async {
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      String sessionId = prefs.getString('sessionId');
      return sessionId;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

call getId function in initState to assign value to the variable "id".

```
@override
 void initState() {
 super.initState();
 getId.then((value) => setState(() {
      id = value;
    }));
}
```

In your build method

```
  ListTile(
              title: Text(
                'Welcome, $id',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
```

Your getId function will return string

```
getId() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String sessionId = prefs.getString('sessionId');
  return sessionId;
}
```